# Regex - not in the list but matched anyway

Tags: regex

This is a bit hard to sum up in a title, but here is my problem:

```
(?:(?:http|https):\\/\\/)?(?:\\/\\/www\\.)?youtube.com\\/watch\\?(?:.*)v=(\\w{11}).*
```

Given the expression given below, I really really don't understand why `ftp://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5eScJmYZZ8` matches. I unsuccessfully tried to add `^` to the expression beginning, but then, my expression does not match anything anymore (this is done in Java, that explains the doubled backslashes).

How can ftp be accepted as it is clearly not listed in (http|ftp)?

**EDIT**

To be accurate, here is what is allowed:

- http(s)://www.[...]
- http(s)://[...]
- www.[...]
- [...]

and nothing else.

Comment: hey, why "Hello dear stackers" was removed from my message? This is my copyrighted introduction!

Comment: If you add `^`, the given link matches too? really?

Comment: I think this `(?:\\/\\/www\\.)?` should be converted to this `(?:www\\.)?`

Comment: that's absolutely right. I am gonna buy new eyes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the leading `(?:(?:http|https):\\/\\/)?` is optional. That's what the question mark at the end of the group signifies (match at most one, i.e. match only if it exists).

A leading `^` should prevent the match with `ftp` though. Can you post the failing regex you tried (with the `^`)?

**UPDATE:**

Aha! It matches without the `^` since the `http` group is optional, and anything can come before the match (e.g. `cheeseyoutube.com/...` would match). Adding a `^` to the beginning of the regex fixes this, but there's another problem with your regex: the `www` group is trying to match two slashes (as first pointed out in [Justin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486732/regex-not-in-the-list-but-matched-anyway/6486782#6486782)), which it can't once the `http` group has already matched those slashes. So the `www` group fails to match (fine, since it's optional), but then the `youtube` part can't match since there's an unmatched `www` in the way!

This should fix your problem:

```
^(?:(?:http|https):\\/\\/)?(?:www\\.)?youtube.com\\/watch\\?(?:.*)v=(\\w{11}).*
```

Comment: @Cameron, but he said that he unsuccessfully tried to add ^ to the expression beginning.

Comment: @Karolis: Right. Adding the `^` just means, "match a string that optionally starts with http|https *with nothing before that*". It's still optional.

Comment: @Karolis: Oh wait, you're totally right. The `^` should prevent that match with `ftp`. Perhaps the OP put it inside the first group?

Comment: in this case, I guess the problems comes from me with Java ^^ The regex defined as follows "^(?:(?:http|https):\\/\\/)?(?:\\/\\/www\\.)?youtube.com\\/watch\\?(?:.*)v=(\\w{11}).*" does not match anything anymore.

Comment: perfect! thanks for the update :D
pfff, I didn't see I included the // in two locations -_-'
Thanks all of you for your help & your time!

Answer (score 3):

Because `?` after the `http` part the means that it is optional. Use `+` instead of `?`.

Also, you are checking for `//` after `http` *twice*.

`\s*` allows whitespace at the beginning. If you don't want to allow whitespace (i.e., the input text will contain only 1 match), use `^` instead.

Here is the working regex that meets all of your added requirements:

```
\s*(?:(http|https)\:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtube.com\/watch\?(?:.*)v=(\w{11}).*
```

Comment: I added a precision in my initial post. I want it to stay optional, with only http or https allowed as protocols.

Comment: Why would you want to match multiple `http://` sections? (`+` means one or more). If you want it non-optional, just omit the `?`.